# How does the carry flag work on the 68000?

Tags: assembly, 68000

So I'm a bit confused about how the carry flag works, specifically on the 68000 processor (but it may not matter).

My main question is as follows:

```
move.b (a0),d0
moveq #7,d1
cmp.b d1,d0
bcc.s DATAErr3
```

Obviously the byte at A0 is being copied to D0, and then D0 is being compared to 7. But then, there is a branch to DATAErr3 if the carry flag is set ("bcc"). In this operation, what values of D0 would cause the carry flag to be set? What values would cause it to not be set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BCC branches if `d0 >= d1`, in an **unsigned** comparison. In this case, the BCC instruction will branch if `d0` is greater than or equal to 7, or is negative.

http://www.easy68k.com/paulrsm/doc/trick68k.htm

Answer (score 3):

As you probably know, `cmp` is actually a subtraction, but without updating destination. For 68000 assembler syntax, destination is always at the right. So `cmp.b d1,d0` command subtracts byte stored in d1 from byte stored in d0 and then discards result, but updates flags according to that operation.
Carry flag is set based on unsigned values in registers.
Therefore, if `d0.b` contains anything from 0 up to 6, subtraction of 7 from 0..6 will generate borrow and set carry flag. `bcc.s` will *not* branch.
When `d0.b` is anything from 7 up to 255, carry will be cleared and `bcc.s` will branch.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at `bcc` and `bcs` is:

- `blo` = `bcs`
- `bhs` = `bcc`

I.e. `bcc` is equivalent to unsigned "higher than or same" condition and `blo` to unsigned "lower than"